# Login configuration script for Junos EX 2200 using minicom

Tags: linux-networking, juniper, junos

I am connecting to Junos OS on Juniper EX-2200 switches using minicom as shown below

```
minicom -C log_sw1 sw1
```

Now I have a series of commands that I need to execute on sw1.(example shown below)

```
cli
request system zeroize
show config
show interface
edit 
delete protocols
set system arp aging-timer 240
```

I want to avoid having to type these commands every time I log into the system.I want to put them in a config file and I want the it to be execute every time I log into the switch using minicom.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[`runscript`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript) is what you're looking for.

```
print "Starting Juniper EX-2200 switch configuration: "
send ""
expect {
    "EX-2200>"
}
send "cli"
expect {
    "..."
}
...
```

Give it a try.